# ¿Como pasar datos en tiempo real a otro Formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Hola a todos estoy trabajando con C# y Windows Form tengo un botón que habré un Formulario que tiene solo un objeto de interfaz tipo ListBox, tengo un método que recive entre otros parámetros parámetros un ListBox donde graba la información, para hacer un Efecto de Consola en Tiempo real.

```
 /*Metodo que Realiza el proceso y envía la información de consola al ListBox*/
 controlador.ExeActualizacionDispositivo(idSeleccionado, lb_consola);
```

Dentro de la funcion la manera en que agrego la información es esta:

```
 consola.Items.Add("Enviando Procedimiento Final: " + SB_ProcedimientoFinal);
```

Donde Consola es el objeto de interfaz lb_consola, pero ahora necesito pasar la interfaz a un nuevo formulario y enviar la información del objeto consola a esa nueva interfaz y se muestre la información en tiempo real.
Como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar informacion a un nuevo formulario  solo debes agregar los que necesites como paramentros al constructor del formulario por ejemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String cadenaRecibida;
    public Form1(String cadenaQueRecibo)
    {
        cadenaRecibida = cadenaQueRecibo;
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

Y para llamar al formulario:

```
Form f = new Form1("cadena que envio");
f.Show();
```

Claro en este ejemplo envio una cadena pero puede ser cualquier objeto